# Variable not defined?

Tags: python, variables

Im a very early beginner in python and need some help. The point of the game is to guess a number and if its not right numguesses adds 1. I know the code is not very efficient but i need it for a project. Heres the code:

```
import random

from datetime import datetime
answer = random.randint(1, 2)
guess = 0
now = datetime.now()
play = 'y'


print 'Welcome to Hi-Lo'
print 'The current time is: ' '%s-%s-%s' % (now.year, now.month, now.day)

while play != 'n':
while guess != answer:
    guess =  int(input('Pick a number inbewteen 1-100 to see if its higher or lower:'))
    if guess == answer:
        numguesses = numguesses + 1
        print 'You are correct! The number was: ' + str(answer)
        print 'It took ' + str(numguesses) + ' guess(es)'
    elif guess > answer:
        print 'Too high'
    else:
        print 'Too low'

play = str(input('Play again? [y/n]?'))
```

And the error that it produces is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:-----------------------------.py", line 17, in <module>
numguesses = numguesses() + 1
```

NameError: name 'numguesses' is not defined

so if somebody could provide a simple explanation for this, i would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: `numguesses` never has an initial value, so how can you add 1 to it? You need `numguesses = 0` before your `while` loops.

Comment: The error message doesn't match the line in the script. Why does it have `()` after `numguesses`?

Comment: You also need to indent the body of `while play != 'n'`

Comment: If you just started using Python, and are on Windows, for your sanity, please install Python **3** now!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set numguesses before you increment it. Try this:

```
import random

from datetime import datetime
answer = random.randint(1, 2)
guess = 0
numguesses = 0
now = datetime.now()
play = 'y'


print 'Welcome to Hi-Lo'
print 'The current time is: ' '%s-%s-%s' % (now.year, now.month, now.day)

while play != 'n':
    while guess != answer:
        guess =  int(input('Pick a number inbewteen 1-100 to see if its higher or lower:'))
        if guess == answer:
            numguesses = numguesses + 1
            print 'You are correct! The number was: ' + str(answer)
            print 'It took ' + str(numguesses) + ' guess(es)'
        elif guess > answer:
            print 'Too high'
        else:
            print 'Too low'

    play = str(input('Play again? [y/n]?'))
```

You also made another error in indenting when nesting your second while loop in your first. I fixed this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `numguesses` a starting value. Try this:

```
numguesses = 0
while guess != answer:
    guess =  int(input('Pick a number inbewteen 1-100 to see if its higher or lower:'))
    if guess == answer:
        numguesses = numguesses + 1
```

Just add `numguesses = 0` before the while loop. You have to declare variables before you use them.

Answer (score 0):

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/env python
  2
  3 import random
  4 from datetime import datetime
  5
  6 answer = random.randint(1, 2)
  7 guess = 0
  8 # You need to define and initialise numguesses before you can increment below by 1
  9 numguesses = 0
 10 now = datetime.now()
 11 play = 'y'
 12
 13 print 'Welcome to Hi-Lo'
 14 print 'The current time is: ' '%s-%s-%s' % (now.year, now.month, now.day)
 15
 16 while play != 'n':
 17   while guess != answer:
 18     guess =  int(input('Pick a number inbewteen 1-100 to see if its higher or lower:'))
 19     if guess == answer:
 20         numguesses = numguesses + 1
 21         print 'You are correct! The number was: ' + str(answer)
 22         print 'It took ' + str(numguesses) + ' guess(es)'
 23         # after the user has guessed correctly, it will start all over again
 24         # hence you need to reset 'guess' and 'numguesses'
 25         guess = 0
 26         numguesses = 0
 27         play = raw_input('Play again? [y/n]? ')
 28         # and you need to get out of the loop altogether if user selects 'n'
 29         break
 30     elif guess > answer:
 31         print 'Too high'
 32         # everytime guess fails, numguesses needs to be increased by 1
 33         numguesses = numguesses + 1
 34     else:
 35         print 'Too low'
 36         # everytime guess fails, numguesses needs to be increased by 1
 37         numguesses = numguesses + 1
```

Please read the comments within the code